# Como diminuir quantidade de if

Tags: php, mysql

O código abaixo deve fazer as seguintes coisas:

1 - Buscar as empresas no banco de dados.

2 - Buscar na tabela no mês quais empresas vão ser trabalhadas.

3 - Nessa tabela do mês é puxado que foi feito com as empresas, tudo e formato (int).

4 - Ai com o resultado dessa segunda busca eu calculo a porcentagem de obrigações feitas em cada empresa.

5 - E também com o resultado eu escrevo na tabela outras informações.

```
<?php
$login_test = new loginController();
$login_test->verif_login();

$_POST = Sanitize::filter($_POST);
$filtro_regime = $_POST['regime'];
$filtro_regime_nome = Components::nome_regime_trib($filtro_regime);

$filtro_empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$filtro_mes_ano = $_POST['mes_ano'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$user = $_SESSION['userCod'];
$nivel = $_SESSION['userLevel'];
$dataD = explode("/", "$filtro_mes_ano");
$m = $dataD[0];
$a = $dataD[1];
//$conecta = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.10", "easy_server", "easy2017", "easy");
$tributacao = $filtro_regime_nome;
?>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.listaEmpresasTabela').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        });

        var pg = "<?php echo $_POST['pg'] ?>";
        var find_pg = '';
        $('.paginate_button a').each(function (i, obj) {
            find_pg = $(this).text();
            if (pg === find_pg) {

                $(this).trigger('click');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table listaEmpresasTabela display table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <?php
                if ($tributacao == 'SIMPLES NACIONAL') {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>CNPJ</th>
                        <th>Inscrição estadual</th>
                        <th>Apuração</th>
                        <th>Data Envio</th>
                        <th>Data Confirmação</th>
                        <th>Sintegra</th>
                        <th>DIFAL / DeSTDA</th>
                        <th>Retenções / CPOM</th>
                        <th>PGDAS</th>
                        <th>Obrigações</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>CNPJ</th>
                        <th>Inscrição estadual</th>
                        <th>Apuração</th>
                        <th>Data Envio</th>
                        <th>Data Confirmação</th>
                        <th>Sped fiscal</th>
                        <th>Sped Contrib</th>
                        <th>Retenções</th>
                        <th>DCTF</th>
                        <th>Obrigações</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                if ($nivel <= 3) {
                    if ($filtro_regime != "0") {
                        $sql = "SELECT id,cod,nome,cnpj,insc_estadual,tributacao FROM empresas_base WHERE tributacao = '$filtro_regime_nome' AND responsavel = '$user' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
                    } else {
                        $sql = "SELECT id,cod,nome,cnpj,insc_estadual,tributacao FROM empresas_base WHERE nome = '$filtro_empresa' AND responsavel = '$user' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($filtro_regime != "0") {
                        $sql = "SELECT id,cod,nome,cnpj,insc_estadual,tributacao FROM empresas_base WHERE tributacao = '$filtro_regime_nome' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
                    } else {
                        $sql = "SELECT id,cod,nome,cnpj,insc_estadual,tributacao FROM empresas_base WHERE nome = '$filtro_empresa' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
                    }
                }
                $rs = Components::get_rs_consulta_query($sql);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
                    $empresaID = $row['id'];
                    $empresaCod = $row['cod'];
                    $empresa = utf8_encode($row['nome']);
                    $cnpj = $row['cnpj'];
                    $insc_est = $row['insc_estadual'];

                    $regime_trib = $row['tributacao'];
                    // verifica pelo POST status se é pra exibir concluidos e incompletos
                    if ($status == '0' OR $status == '2') {
                        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM controle_fiscal WHERE empresa = '$empresaCod' AND mes_correspondente = '$m' AND ano_correspondente = '$a' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id ";
                    } else {
                        if ($tributacao == 'SIMPLES NACIONAL') {
                            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM controle_fiscal WHERE empresa = '$empresaCod' AND mes_correspondente = '$m' AND ano_correspondente = '$a' AND data_envio != '' AND data_confirmacao != '' AND sintegra != '0' AND difal_destda != '0' AND retencoes_cpom != '0' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
                        } elseif ($tributacao == 'PRESUMIDO' OR $tributacao == 'REAL') {
                            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM controle_fiscal WHERE empresa = '$empresaCod' AND mes_correspondente = '$m' AND ano_correspondente = '$a' AND data_envio != '' AND data_confirmacao != '' AND sped_fiscal != '0' AND sped_contrib != '0' AND dctf != '0' AND retencoes != '0' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id";
                        }
                    }
                    $rs2 = Components::get_rs_consulta_query($sql2);
                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs2)) {
                        $porc_form = 0;
                        //Todos
                        $apuracao = $row2['apuracao'];
                        $recibo_simples = $row2['recibo_simples'];
                        $controle_cod = $row2['cod'];
                        $data_envio = $row2['data_envio'];
                        $data_confirmacao = $row2['data_confirmacao'];
                        //Simples
                        $sintegra = $row2['sintegra'];
                        $difal_destda = $row2['difal_destda'];
                        $retencoes_cpom = $row2['retencoes_cpom'];
                        //Presumido
                        $sped_fiscal = $row2['sped_fiscal'];
                        $sped_contrib = $row2['sped_contrib'];
                        $dctf = $row2['dctf'];
                        $retencoes = $row2['retencoes'];
                        $pgdas = $row2['pgdas'];

                        if ($insc_est == 'CANCELADA' OR $insc_est == "INATIVA" OR $insc_est == 'ISENTO') {

                            if ($data_envio != 0) {
                                $data_envio_inativa = '';
                            } else {

                                $data_envio_inativa = 'Nada a enviar';
                            }

                            if ($data_confirmacao != 0) {
                                $data_confirmacao_inativa = '';
                            } else {

                                $data_confirmacao_inativa = 'Nada a confirmar';
                            }
                            if ($apuracao != 0) {

                                $apuracao_inativa = '';
                            } else {

                                $apuracao_inativa = 'Nada a apurar';
                            }

                            if ($tributacao == 'PRESUMIDO' OR $tributacao == "REAL") {
                                $retencoes_inativa = "Não necessário";
                                $sped_fiscal_inativa = 'Não necessário';
                                $sped_contrib_inativa = 'Não necessário';
                                $dctf_inativa = '';
                                $sintegra_inativa = '';
                                $difal_inativa = '';
                                $retencoes_cpom_inativa = '';
                                $sped_fiscal = '';
                                $sped_contrib = '';
                                $retencoes = '';
                            } elseif ($tributacao == 'SIMPLES NACIONAL') {
                                //$pgdas_inativa = 'Não necessário';
                                $retencoes_inativa = "";
                                $sped_fiscal_inativa = '';
                                $sped_contrib_inativa = '';
                                $sintegra_inativa = 'Não necessário';
                                $difal_inativa = 'Não necessário';
                                $retencoes_cpom_inativa = 'Não necessário';
                                $retencoes_cpom = '';
                                $difal_destda = '';
                                $sintegra = '';
                            }
                        } else {
                            $data_envio_inativa = '';
                            $data_confirmacao_inativa = '';
                            $apuracao_inativa = '';
                            $sintegra_inativa = '';
                            $pgdas_inativa = '';
                            $difal_inativa = '';
                            $retencoes_cpom_inativa = '';
                            $retencoes_inativa = "";
                            $dctf_inativa = '';
                            $sped_fiscal_inativa = '';
                            $sped_contrib_inativa = '';
                        }
                        if ($data_confirmacao == '' AND $data_envio != '') {
                            $data_envio_formated = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data_envio);

                            $datetime1 = $data_envio_formated->format('Y-m-d');
                            $datetime2 = date('Y-m-d');
                            $time_inicial = strtotime($datetime1);
                            $time_final = strtotime($datetime2);
                            $diferenca = $time_final - $time_inicial; // 19522800 segundos
                            $dias = (int) floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));
                            if ($dias == 1) {
                                $data_confirmacao = 'Enviado ontem.';
                                $data_confirmacao_td_class = 'default';
                            } elseif ($dias < 5) {

                                $data_confirmacao = "A " . $dias . " dias sem confirmação";
                                $data_confirmacao_td_class = "warning";
                            } else {

                                $data_confirmacao = "ATENÇÃO! A " . $dias . " dias sem confirmação";
                                $data_confirmacao_td_class = "danger";
                            }
                        } else {
                            $data_confirmacao_td_class = "";
                            $data_confirmacao = $row2['data_confirmacao'];
                        }

                        if ($apuracao != 0) {
                            $apuracao_val = 1;
                        } else {
                            $apuracao_val = 0;
                        }
                        if ($apuracao != 0) {
                            $data_envio_val = 1;
                            $data_confirmacao_val = 1;
                        } else {
                            if ($data_envio != '' || $data_envio != 0) {
                                $data_envio_val = 1;
                            } else {
                                $data_envio_val = 0;
                            }

                            if ($data_confirmacao != '' || $data_confirmacao != 0) {
                                $data_confirmacao_val = 1;
                            } else {
                                $data_confirmacao_val = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        if ($insc_est == 'ISENTO' OR $insc_est == 'CANCELADA') {
                            $sintegra_val = 1;
                            $recibo_simples = 1;
                            if ($pgdas != 0) {
                                $pgdas_val = 1;
                            } else {
                                $pgdas_val = 0;
                            }
                            $difal_destda_val = 1;
                            $retencoes_cpom_val = 1;
                            $apuracao_val = 1;
                            $sped_fiscal_val = 1;
                            $sped_contrib_val = 1;
                            $retencoes_val = 1;
                                $val_obrig = $apuracao_val + $data_envio_val + $data_confirmacao_val + $sped_fiscal_val + $sped_contrib_val + $dctf_val + $retencoes_val;
                                $porc_form = (($val_obrig * 100) / 7);

                        } else {
                            if ($tributacao == 'SIMPLES NACIONAL') {
                                if ($sintegra != 0) {
                                    $sintegra_val = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $sintegra_val = 0;
                                }

                                if ($recibo_simples != 0) {
                                    $recibo_simples_val = 1;
                                    $pgdas_val = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $recibo_simples_val = 0;
                                    if ($pgdas != 0) {
                                        $pgdas_val = 1;
                                    } else {
                                        $pgdas_val = 0;
                                    }
                                }

                                if ($difal_destda != 0) {
                                    $difal_destda_val = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $difal_destda_val = 0;
                                }

                                if ($retencoes_cpom != 0) {
                                    $retencoes_cpom_val = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $retencoes_cpom_val = 0;
                                }


                                $val_obrig = $apuracao_val + $data_envio_val + $data_confirmacao_val + $sintegra_val + $recibo_simples_val + $difal_destda_val + $retencoes_cpom_val + $pgdas_val;

                                $porc_form = (($val_obrig * 100) / 8);
                            } elseif ($tributacao == 'PRESUMIDO' || $tributacao == "REAL") {

                                if ($sped_fiscal != 0) {
                                    $sped_fiscal_val = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $sped_fiscal_val = 0;
                                }


                                if ($sped_contrib != 0) {
                                    $sped_contrib_val = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $sped_contrib_val = 0;
                                }

                                if ($dctf != 0) {
                                    $dctf_val = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $dctf_val = 0;
                                }

                                if ($retencoes != 0) {
                                    $retencoes_val = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $retencoes_val = 0;
                                }
                                $val_obrig = $apuracao_val + $data_envio_val + $data_confirmacao_val + $sped_fiscal_val + $sped_contrib_val + $dctf_val + $retencoes_val;
                                $porc_form = (($val_obrig * 100) / 7);


                                $sped_fiscal_sum += $sped_fiscal_val;
                                $sped_contrib_sum += $sped_contrib_val;
                                $retencoes_sum += $retencoes_val;
                                $dctf_sum += $dctf_val;
                            }
                        }

                        if ($apuracao == '1') {
                            $data_envio = ' - Nada a enviar';
                            $data_confirmacao = ' - Nada a confirmar';
                        } else {
                            $data_envio = $data_envio;
                            $data_confirmacao = $data_confirmacao;
                        }
                        $tr_styles = fiscalModel::get_tr_obrigacoes_stats($status, $tributacao, $apuracao, $recibo_simples, $data_envio, $data_confirmacao, $sintegra, $difal_destda, $retencoes_cpom, $dctf, $retencoes, $pgdas, $sped_contrib, $sped_fiscal);
                        ?>
                        <tr style='<?php echo $tr_styles['display_none'] ?>'class="seleciona_empresa <?php echo $tr_styles['display_tr'] ?>" data-empresa="<?php echo $empresaCod ?>" data-empresa_nome="<?php echo $empresa ?>" data-controle='<?php echo $controle_cod ?>'>
                            <td width="2%">
                                <?php echo $empresaID ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="16%">
                                <?php echo $empresa ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%">
                                <?php echo $cnpj ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%">
                                <?php echo $insc_est ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%">
                                <?php echo $apuracao_inativa . Components::nome_apuracoes($apuracao) ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%">
                                <?php echo $data_envio . $data_envio_inativa ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%" class="<?php echo $data_confirmacao_td_class ?>">
                                <?php echo $data_confirmacao . $data_confirmacao_inativa ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%">
                                <?php echo $sintegra_inativa . $sped_fiscal_inativa . Components::sintegra_nome($sintegra) . Components::sped_fiscal_nome($sped_fiscal); ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%">
                                <?php echo $difal_inativa . $sped_contrib_inativa . Components::difal_destda_nome($difal_destda) . Components::sped_contrib_nome($sped_contrib); ?>
                            </td>
                            <td width="8%" >
                                <?php echo $retencoes_cpom_inativa . $retencoes_inativa . Components::retencoes_cpom_nome($retencoes_cpom) . Components::retencoes_nome($retencoes) ?>
                            </td>
                            <?php
                            if ($tributacao == 'SIMPLES NACIONAL') {
                                ?>
                                <td width="8%">
                                    <?php echo $pgdas_inativa . Components::pgdas_nome($pgdas) ?>
                                </td>
                                <?php
                            } elseif ($tributacao == 'PRESUMIDO' OR $tributacao = "REAL") {
                                ?>
                                <td width="8%">
                                    <?php echo $dctf_inativa . Components::get_dctf_nome($dctf) ?>
                                </td>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <td width="6%">
                                <?php echo number_format($porc_form, 2, '.', '') . "%"; ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .listaEmpresasTabela tr{
        border: 2px solid #000;
    }
    .listaEmpresasTabela tr td{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        margin:1px;
        z-index: 0;

    }
    .listaEmpresasTabela tr td:hover{
        border:1px solid #999;
        z-index: 1;
        margin:1px;

    }
    .dataTables_wrapper .row:first-child {
        border:1px dashed #ccc;
        margin: 0px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
    .table thead tr th{
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
```

Essa tabela é muito condicional e como o que devem ser exibidas nela.

Comment: Precisa estrutura melhor a lógica no `if ($nivel <= 3) {` tem código duplicado ... quebrar trechos de códigos em funções, agrupar elementos em um array podem ajudar.

Comment: Uma dica: Quando estiver trabalhando com `php` e `html`, utilize blocos de código para [escapá-los](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) invés das aberturas de `{}`, ficará mais legível. Exemplo: `<?php if(condition): ?> HTML aqui <?php endif; ?> `

Answer (score -2):

Um bom começo é extrair a lógica que está em PHP para pequenas funções.

Por exemplo, códigos como o abaixo podem ser alterados da seguinte forma:

```
if ($data_confirmacao != 0) {
  $data_confirmacao_inativa = '';
} else {
  $data_confirmacao_inativa = 'Nada a confirmar';
}
```

Mover para uma função:

```
function mesagem_data_confirmacao($data_confirmacao) {
  if ($data_confirmacao != 0) {
    return '';
  }
  return 'Nada a confirmar';
}

$data_confirmacao_inativa = mesagem_data_confirmacao($data_confirmacao);
```

Terá de escrever um pouco mais, mas assim deixará o código da tabela mais legível e fácil de dar manutenção.